# Memory address for struct not visible

Tags: go

In Go, I was confused about why the memory address for variables like int can be obtained but not for structs. As an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
stud1 := stud{"name1", "school1"}
a:=10
fmt.Println("&a is:", &a)
fmt.Println("&stud1 is:",&stud1)
}
```

output is:

```
&a is: 0x20818a220
&stud1 is: &{name1 school1}
```

Why is &a giving the memory address, however &stud1 not giving the exact memory location. I don't have any intention of using the memory address but just was curious about the different behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the [`fmt`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package uses reflection to print out values, and there is a specific case to print a pointer to a struct as `&{Field Value}`.

If you want to see the memory address, use the pointer formatting verb `%p`.

```
fmt.Printf("&stud is: %p\n", &stud)
```